# Node Express API not accepting DELETE requests

Tags: node.js, express

I've been on this for a while now, and I just can't understand it.

Consider the following route:

```
app.delete('/users/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Handling delete request...");
    return res.send(204);
});
```

When I make a DELETE request it times out. GET, PUT and POST requests are all working fine.

I am using EmberJS with ember-data making the requests via AJAX.

I have tried curl from the terminal:

```
curl -i -X DELETE http://localhost:9000/users/12345
```

for which I get the following response:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Operation timed out
```

I have also changed the route to:

```
app.del('/users/:id', function(req, res){ ... });
```

But express complains that I should be using app.delete...

I have Access-Control-Allow-Methods set like so:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Here's the server.js file to give some context:

```
var config = require("./config"),
    tokens = require("./tokens"),
    bcrypt = require("bcrypt"),
    nodemailer = require("nodemailer"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    zip = require("adm-zip"),
    path = require("path"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    express = require("express"),
    limit = require("limit"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    winston = require("winston"),
    multer = require("multer"),
    img = require('easyimage'),
    app = express();

//set up prerender
app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', '*****')); // For google spiders

//set up logging
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({
            level: 'info',
            colorize: true,
            handleExceptions: true
        }),
        new (winston.transports.File)({ 
            filename: '../logs/node_api.log',
            colorize: false,
            json: false,
            handleExceptions: true
        })
    ]
});

//set up mailer
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP", {
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "*****",
        pass: "*****"
    }
});

//set up DB connection and pass to routes.
console.log("connecting to db... ");
mongoose.connect(config.mongodb.url);
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function(err) {
    logger.error(err);
});

console.log("dependencies loaded...");

db.on('open', function() {
    console.log("db connection opened...");
    //models...
    var user = require('./models/user')(app, mongoose),
        property = require('./models/property')(app, mongoose),
        viewing = require('./models/viewing')(app, mongoose),
        valuation = require('./models/valuation')(app, mongoose),
        page = require('./models/page')(app, mongoose),
        content_block = require('./models/content_block')(app, mongoose),
        area = require('./models/area')(app, mongoose, user, property);

    //routes...
    require('./routes/uploads')(app, img, fs, tokens, logger);
    require('./routes/auth')(app, user, bcrypt, tokens, logger);
    require('./routes/properties')(app, property, user, viewing, fs, tokens, smtpTransport, logger);
    require('./routes/users')(app, user, tokens, bcrypt, smtpTransport, logger);
    require('./routes/valuation')(app, valuation, user, smtpTransport, logger);
    require('./routes/pages')(app, page, tokens, logger);
    require('./routes/areas')(app, area, logger);
    require('./routes/content_blocks')(app, content_block, logger);

    //cron
    require('./cron')(property, fs, path, zip, logger);

    console.log("routes loaded...");

    //TODO: only needed locally
    app.get('/api/uploads/:filename', function(req, res) {
        var path = './uploads/' + req.params.filename;

        fs.readFile(path, function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                if(err.errno === 34) return res.send(404);
                else return res.send(500, err);
            }
            return res.sendfile(path);
        });
    });

    console.log("static content server implemented...");
});

//TODO: Clean up tmp folder with BodyParser to avoid server attacks
app.use(bodyParser({
    uploadDir: '/uploads/',
    keepExtensions: true
}));

console.log("body-parser started...");

// app.use(limit('5mb'));
app.all("/*", function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, token, Origin, Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
    return next();
});

console.log("Access-Control-Allow headers set...");

app.all("/*", function(req, res, next) {

    if (req.method.toLowerCase() !== "options") return next();

    return res.send(204);
});

console.log("catch all routes implemented...");

// Setup image uploads without bodyParser
app.use(multer({
    dest: 'uploads/',
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return filename.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    }
}));

console.log("multer started...");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if(err) logger.error(err);
});

app.listen(9000, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        logger.error("Unable to listen for connections", error);
        process.exit(10);
    }
    logger.info("Brik - Express is listening on localhost:9000");
});
```

Comment: Probably because the status code `204` means no response.

Comment: @BenFortune HTTP 204 shouldn't trigger a "recv failure" by curl. 204 just means "this response does not have a body.", its does not mean "dont write data to this socket" ;)

Comment: I should still get a 204 response from the HTTP request, and a log in the console. At the moment I'm getting a timeout error.

Comment: Can you add some context like middlewares you are using or some more of you app-related code? Can't find an error (beside the missing ")") in your post yet.

Comment: So the issue seems to have resolved itself...

I created a delete route on a different endpoint:

    app.delete('/alerts/:id', [function]);

which resolved fine, so I went back and changed the users delete route, and it resolved correctly. A couple of things spring to mind as to what might have happened:

There was some kind of a server issue
Express requires that routes are instantiated in a specific order (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)?